Remove border between Excel and PPT for a copy and paste VBA
I have an issue with a simple copy and paste in VBA. Find below the code. The issue is the PastePicture create grey borders useless and I do not want them. I searched on Internet but nothing works. Could you please help me to remove those borders on my Paste?
Sub CopyAndPaste()

Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim PPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As Object

Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String

strPresPath = "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx"
strExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\pppppppp"
    
Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    
Set PPTFile = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
    

'Step 1 Copy the data

Workbooks("Globalyyyy").Worksheets("ILLUSTRATIONS CHARTS").Range("B58:G69").CopyPicture

Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Step 2 Paste the data

Set mySlide = PPTFile.Slides(5)

With mySlide

mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPastePicture 'DataType:=ppEnhancedMetafile
    
End With


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True



Do the cells in your range have a white background? If so, change it to "none" (e.g. myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0). Same if you want to copy a chart: myChart.PlotArea.ClearFormats.

As @Haluk mentioned, you have to "erase" the cell borders by drawing them as the background color. The code below is an example for how to accomplish this.
I've included a bonus function for attaching to PowerPoint that I find very useful.
Option Explicit

Sub CopyAndPaste()
    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPTApp = AttachToMSPowerPointApplication
    PPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    
    Dim PPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set PPTFile = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
    
    Dim mySlide As Object
    PPTFile.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutText
    Set mySlide = PPTFile.Slides(1)
    
    Dim myData As Range
    Set myData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ILLUSTRATIONS CHARTS").Range("B58:G69")
    
    'Step 0 - "erase" the grid lines
    With myData.Borders
        '--- you can optionally save the existing setting for the borders,
        '    then return them to their original state when you're done
        Dim ogLineStyle As XlLineStyle
        Dim ogColor As XlColorIndex
        Dim ogWeight As Long
        ogLineStyle = .LineStyle
        ogWeight = .Weight
        ogColor = .Color
        
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = myData.Interior.Color 'set to same as background color
        .Weight = xlThin
    
        'Step 1 Copy the data
        myData.CopyPicture
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'Step 2 Paste the data
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial
        
        'Step 3 restore the original borders
        .LineStyle = ogLineStyle
        .Color = ogColor
        .Weight = ogWeight
    End With

End Sub

Public Function AttachToMSPowerPointApplication() As PowerPoint.Application
    '--- finds an existing and running instance of MS PowerPoint, or starts
    '    the application if one is not already running
    Dim msppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set msppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If Err > 0 Then
        '--- we have to start one
        '    an exception will be raised if the application is not installed
        Set msppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    Set AttachToMSPowerPointApplication = msppApp
End Function


You have to either manually or programmatically uncheck the Gridlines box in View tab,before the copy method.
